# Iterate over lines of document in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a document called words, and each line has a new word. I want to turn each one of these words into a list of its constituent characters. I do this by just doing `list(x)` where x is the word.

This is what I am doing, but I want a way to parallelize this:

```
split = []
with open('wordprob.txt','rt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        split.append(list(line))
```

I am using this approach so that I do not have to load the entire file (over 3 gb) into memory. When parallelizing it by loading the file first, my memory usage goes over 16 gb.

How can I parallelize it without loading the file into memory, just like in the loop above?

Thanks!

EDIT: Below it was pointed out that the list will take up lots of memory. Instead, how would I store each list of characters (originally from a single word) as a space delimited string on a new line of a new document. Again, I'm looking for a parallelized solution.

Comment: But you are storing the entire _list_ in memory, and the list will be _much_ larger than the text file. Maybe tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: @RayToal Okay, makes sense. Can we store each set of characters as space delimited values in a new file, each word (now characters) on a separate line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have a file such as

```
sushi
banana
sujuk
strawberry
tomato
pho
ramen
manaqish
```

and you want to produce a *new file* like this:

```
s u s h i
b a n a n a
s u j u k
s t r a w b e r r y
t o m a t o
p h o
r a m e n
m a n a q i s h
```

then you can write a simple stdin-stdout program, something like

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(' '.join(list(line)))
```

If all the data goes to the same file, then even if you parallelize, each of your threads or processes will be competing to write to the same output file.

If you really want to parallelize and you want to stick with Python, you can use Hadoop Streaming. Your job will be a mapper-only job; in fact the mapper is the three line script above. But I'm not sure this buys you much unless your data set is ridiculously large. The transformation is pretty simple, but feel free to profile the job to see if you get much benefit.

I don't think 3GB is very much, but this can be a fun exercise in Hadoop (or whatever the kids are using these days.)

Comment: Is a reducer needed at all? What would that look like? If you could guide me through this I would really appreciate it - I have never used Hadoop before.

Comment: There's definitely a bit of a learning curve with Hadoop but the basic idea is that you have a massive file (can be line oriented). The file is partitioned into pieces and the mappers transform each line (or each object) of each piece. Then the chunks are sorted by keys and the reducers put them all back together in a single output. Your job needs no reducer. You are just mapping strings into strings-with-spaces. You are not going to see much speed up because the time it takes to split words is not much more than the time to just read/write everything.